# Plumbing drain detour around steel beam

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

During a remodel we removed a 1st floor load-bearing wall that included a drain stack serving our laundry room on the 2nd floor. A steel beam was added in the ceiling above the removed wall to handle the load. The 2nd floor drain pipe for the laundry was extended into the room adjacent to the laundry room a few inches, down into the joist bay next to the steel beam, and then perpendicular through a few additional joists to connect to drain in another wall.

The room adjacent to the laundry room is our master bedroom and I'd like to avoid the drain protrusion into this room as it adds an awkward soffit in the middle of the room (or we could fur out the wall at significant cost and some sqft loss). However, doing this would route the drain in an odd 180 degree path that looks odd on paper, but seems sound to me.

Does this drain design have any glaring issues before I propose it to the plumber?
[image: Current plumbing]

Current plumbing the plumber installed - washer stand pipe/p-trap goes into a sanitary tee, vent above and drain below into a 45* that juts into bedroom slightly - enough that drywall and baseboard would not cover it.

--

[image: View from laundry room]

My proposal, viewed from the laundry room - vertical sanitary tee replaced with horizontal combo and 2x 22* fittings to offset drain into laundry room (this will be covered with cabinets). Drain continues into nearby exterior wall. Also shown is a p-trap for a laundry sink.

--

[image: Alternate angle]

Another view showing what happens in the exterior wall. Laundry drain enters a 2" x 1 1/2" x 2" sanitary tee angled at 45*, a short stretch of pipe, then a 45* fitting to vertical down into the joist bay. From there a 90* sweep takes the drain back to where the current 45* juts into the bedroom.

Also shown for the laundry sink, a 1 1/2" sanitary tee angled at 45* connects to the laundry sanitary tee (also at 45*) and a vent for the sink.

--

[image: Top view]

Here you can see how the drain makes about an 8' detour through the wall to save me the headache of a pipe in our bedroom. There is enough height for slope to accommodate the additional distance.

--

Also, because someone might comment on it (I certainly did) the AHJ inspector reviewed and agreed with the ABS->PVC->ABS transitions. I do not understand why the plumber installed this one short section with PVC and used ABS everywhere else (it's all new).